# How to calculate value from select fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I took the example from here http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/, *Demo 4***

Everything works fine, however I can not figure out how to calculate the sum from select list values and to withdraw at the end of the page. I try to do it with this code but it not work `

```
<section class="main clearfix">
                <div class="fleft">
                    <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
                        <option value="-1" selected>Choose a weather condition</option>
                        <option value="1" class="icon-sun">Sun</option>
                        <option value="2" class="icon-cloudy">Clouds</option>
                        <option value="3" class="icon-weather">Snow</option>
                        <option value="4" class="icon-rainy">Rain</option>
                        <option value="5" class="icon-windy">Windy</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="text" id="sum">
            </section>
```

```
    $( function() {

            $( '#cd-dropdown' ).dropdown( {
                gutter : 5,
                delay : 40,
                rotated : 'left'
            } );

        });

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#cd-dropdown").change(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $.each($(".cd-select") ,function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
            $("#sum").val(total)});
```

`

**Thank you in advance !**

Comment: So, how many this `cd-select` elements you have?

Comment: What is currently happening? How does it differ from expectations?

Comment: What library are you using for the dropdown?  Maybe the third party library is causing an issue.  Without much other insight into what's going wrong, I can't see what's wrong with it. https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/yc8Lc4sL/

Comment: I also think so, because when i put away the jquery.dropdown.js that works ok. So if you look at link above you will see the example and code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cd-select").change(function () {
        total = 0;
        $('.cd-select').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != "-1") {
                total = total + parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
            }
        });
        $('#sum').val(total);
    });
});


 <div class="fleft">
                <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
                    <option value="-1" selected>Choose a weather condition</option>
                    <option value="1" class="icon-sun">Sun</option>
                    <option value="2" class="icon-cloudy">Clouds</option>
                    <option value="3" class="icon-weather">Snow</option>
                    <option value="4" class="icon-rainy">Rain</option>
                    <option value="5" class="icon-windy">Windy</option>
                </select>

                <select id="Select1" class="cd-select">
                    <option value="-1" selected>Choose a weather condition</option>
                    <option value="1" class="icon-sun">Sun</option>
                    <option value="2" class="icon-cloudy">Clouds</option>
                    <option value="3" class="icon-weather">Snow</option>
                    <option value="4" class="icon-rainy">Rain</option>
                    <option value="5" class="icon-windy">Windy</option>
                </select>
                <select id="Select2" class="cd-select">
                    <option value="-1" selected>Choose a weather condition</option>
                    <option value="1" class="icon-sun">Sun</option>
                    <option value="2" class="icon-cloudy">Clouds</option>
                    <option value="3" class="icon-weather">Snow</option>
                    <option value="4" class="icon-rainy">Rain</option>
                    <option value="5" class="icon-windy">Windy</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="sum">
```

> ```
>  When any select with class 'cd-select' change the sum will be calculated and displayed on the text field
> ```

Comment: A big blob of code with no explanation is not a proper answer. It explains absolutely nothing. Presumably all you are trying to show is that the code can work...which is nothing more than a comment

Comment: @charlietfl When any select with class 'cd-select' change the sum will be calculated and displayed on the text field

Comment: And it would with OP code also .. if plugin wasn't causing issues

Comment: @charlietfl OK. Will try :)

Answer (score -1):

Summation is not being made as you expect because your `total` variable is reset to `0` every time the event listener is fired. Thus your code will work if you define that variable as global.

Thus what you want is:

```
var total = 0;

$("#cd-dropdown").change(function() {
  $.each($(".cd-select"), function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  $("#sum").val(total)
});
```

Comment: Probably actually want `$.each($(".cd-select > option:selected")` to count only the *selected* options, rather than *all* of them.

Comment: It's not a multiple select... this answer doesn't make sense either and will add values that are not selected

Comment: I totally agree with both of you. I updated my answer ;)  @Draco18s

Comment: Assuming there are more than one `<select>` result would be the same as what OP is doing. `$('select').val()` is perfectly valid. There is no need for global variable either

Comment: @charlietfl yeah! I learnt something new with you now. Thank you! Question wasn't that clear for me, but now I think I got the point and provided the right answer. Thank you once again

Comment: When i put away the jquery.dropdown.js that works ok. So if you look at link above you will see the example and code. This is the link: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/

Comment: @Arthur in that case you need to use the events triggered by the plugin instead of using `change`. It would seem that the plugin isn't triggering the change event internally